# Pilot Switch as an indicator

Tags: pilot-light

I have a Leviton 5628-2W with a pilot light that indicates when the switch is in the on position.  I use the switch to control a light that is some distance away and out of site from the switch location.  Can I wire the switch in a way that will indicate that the light is actually on and not just that the switch is in the on position?

Comment: Is that not the way it works already?  If the light burns out, I'm not sure the pilot light will turn on, and how would the light ever be on if the switch was off?

Comment: My preferred approach to this problem is cheap plastic optical fiber. Otherwise, yup, will depend on how the switch/pilot is set up, and many will not indicate if the light is not working if power is on.

Comment: How probable is it for the light not to be on? Are you expecting a wiring failure, or a bulb failure?  I am sensing an XY problem.

Comment: Are you rigidly locked to that specific model of switch, or is replacing the switch with a different device acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could add a smart CT and adjust it to turn the pilot light on when current is being used, I use these to monitor equipment , if a belt or chain breaks the motor is not drawing enough so it turns on an alarm. The same process could be used with a pilot lamp type switch if it has separate contacts (not integrated) for the lamp.